# Keyboard shortcut to close the ads on YouTube

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, youtube

I am wondering if there is any keyboard shortcut to close the ads (advertisement) on YouTube.

For example, as the one as in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: 4 `tab` + `enter`, will skip ads. and `m` will mute & unmute the sound.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- The keyboard shortcut to skip the ad at the beginning of a video is <kbd>Tab</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- There is no keyboard shortcut to skip ads in the middle of the video.

### Other things to try

1. Install [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (Firefox) or [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) (Chrome) either of which allows you to install userscripts in your browser.

   - Then,  install the "[Auto Close YouTube Ads](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/9165-auto-close-youtube-ads)" from Greasy Fork.
   - This approach doesn't block YouTube ads but instead makes them bearable. Site owners and content creators still receive revenue.
2. Get an Ad Blocker.  For Chrome, I recommend [uBlock Origin](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm).

   - Note that this approach actually blocks the ads and denies income to the site owner and content creators.

Answer (score 4):

Answering OP question about keyboard shortcut:

The location of close (`x`) icon (as of 2019 Oct) is one `tab` back from `timeline`. As I noted depending on some factors starting active control could be different, so in general solution is as suggested briefly by other answer, I add more details.

If you just skipped (e.g. forward) via timeline, it's active and then to close ad as on the picture of OP question:

`SHIFT-TAB` then `SPACEBAR`

If not, click `TAB` repeatedly and see how active control change (I noted it's usually 3 or 4 times to `x` control icon), if you can clearly see it's `x` icon, then click `space`, otherwise click until `timeline` is active, then one time `shift-tab` and then `space`.

Works on Firefox 67 on Linux on Thinkpad, please add comments those who try for other browsers/OS/devices.

P.S. learned to navigate yourtube via keyboard during that exercise, just one useful tip - pausing/resume via `spacebar` works when `timeline` is active.

Comment: Tried and it works in Chrome on MacBook exactly as written, I think success depends not on operating system, but on current state of youtube site layout. But in case of small changes the approach may remain valid with small variations.

Answer (score 1):

This answer doesn't directly relate to your specific keyboard shortcut, but I thought I'd mention it anyways since alternatives are being mentioned.

Ironically, given the ad is for Raspberry Pi beta testers, another option for hiding/blocking the ads is to purchase a Raspberry Pi and set up [Pi-Hole](https://pi-hole.net) which can be used to block ads network wide.

> The Pi-hole can block ads for all devices on your network.  All you need is a Raspberry Pi connected to your router.  It was inspired as a low-cost, open source alternative to the AdTrap.
>
> Currently, over...1.6 million (if you decide to use the mahakala source list) domains known to serve advertisements can be blocked before they even reach your computer.  The list of these domains are maintained by different sites across the Internet.   The Pi-hole queries these sites and compiles them into an aggregated list, which is then stored on the Raspberry Pi to block advertisements.

From [here](http://jacobsalmela.com/block-millions-ads-network-wide-with-a-raspberry-pi-hole-2-0/).

Answer (score 1):

Just hit TAB the necessary number of times and hit SPACEBAR when the X is highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut to skip ads in mid video is <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.